# How can a program measure device size in AIX?

Tags: c, gcc, aix

My C program mounts a raw device, then lseeks to its end to find the length. This works well in Linux and Windows, but fails in AIX - apparently you can seek to any location, even past the end. Any idea on how to do it correctly in C?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used AIX, but have you tried using `read`.  It may fail either at or past the end, so you could do binary search for the end using `seek` and `read`, maybe.